# What's the term for when you end up with the same number on both sides of an equation?

Tags: terminology

If you have like $-4(5x-10)=2(6x+4)$, then if you distribute and subtract and add on both sides and that stuff you end up with $32=32$. I know there's a mathematical term for that, I think it starts with an I. What is it?

Comment: An identity maybe?

Comment: Here, we do not end with an identity. Is there a typo somewhere ?

Comment: If every real number is a solution, we could consider the equation to be a tautology.

Comment: Somehow, you lost $x$ in your manipulations. Your equation simplifies to $32 = 32x$, i.e., $x=1$.